# connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly

Tags: php, laravel

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (SQL: select * from `products`)

this is my env

DB_CONNECTION=mysql

DB_LIVE_HOST="********"

DB_LIVE_PORT="3306"

DB_LIVE_DATABASE="mavenvet_mavenvet_test"

DB_LIVE_USERNAME="******"

DB_LIVE_PASSWORD="******"

```
'online' => [
        'driver' => env('DB_CONNECTION'),
        'host' => env('DB_LIVE_HOST', '......'),
        'port' => env('DB_LIVE_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_LIVE_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_LIVE_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_LIVE_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

$live_database = DB::connection('online');

```
    // Connect ot local database
    $local_database = DB::connection('mysql');

    //get dataa table form the live database
    $live_admission_table = $live_database->table('products')->get();
    for ($a = 0, $b = count($live_admission_table); $a < $b; ++$a) {
        $live_admission_table[$a] = (array) $live_admission_table+[$a];
    }

    //get data tabel from local database
    $local_admission_table = $local_database->table('admissions')->get();
    for ($a = 0, $b = count($local_admission_table); $a < $b; ++$a) {
        $local_admission_table[$a] = (array) $local_admission_table+[$a];
```

Comment: Looks like that database server is down or blocking tcp port.  Is that a remote server?  Have they the port open for you?  If it is a remote server, in mysql usually they have to open port 3306 widely or just for you if behind a firewall

Comment: DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_LIVE_HOST="104.194.10.93"
DB_LIVE_PORT="3306"
DB_LIVE_DATABASE="mavenvet_mavenvet_test"
DB_LIVE_USERNAME="hfijkgfi"
DB_LIVE_PASSWORD="jhegrf"

Comment: please can you help me out .. i have been on this for a week now

Comment: You should not put users and passwords here. REMOVE THEM or fake them.

Comment: Seems the port is closed from my side, so I guess also from your machine where from you are executing the code.  Try to do a `telnet 104.194.10.93 3306` from its shell to know if that port is open from your machine.  If not then you should contact the owner of that database and ask him to let your machine IP to pass the firewall.  The same for this IP: 199.188.200.146 that correspons to that domain: `'host' => env('DB_LIVE_HOST', 'mavenvetconsult.com')`